# Hibernate select with birectionnal mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

On a bidirectional relationship beetwen two entities (a ControlTable made up of ControlSteps), i'm simply trying by different ways to request a ControlTable by knowing the collection ControlSteps of it. I know that it's not recommended to have this bidirectionnal mapping but i need to know each childs of a parent, and the parent for each child.

I configured it like this in ControlTable class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "controlTable",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<ControlStep> controlSteps;
```

And like this for ControlStep class :

```
@ManyToOne(optional=false, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="ctrl_table_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ControlTable controlTable;
```

When i use the default JPA query findAll(), it's not working to get the list of ControlTables (or only one) because it's requesting recursively the parent in the child's parent (infinite response).
In another way, itried to put all in LAZY loading, with an HQL query fetching the childs, but the result is the same.

Do you have any idea of how to get these collections without problems?

Thank you very much by advance

Comment: FYI The JPA API has no such "findAll". Spring Data JPA (!= JPA API) does have such a method

Comment: You are right, i missed to mention "Spring data". Sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The problem was Spring Data Rest and JSON transformation, for more details :

[Infinite Recursion with Jackson JSON and Hibernate JPA issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue/18288939#18288939])